# asynchronously function set variable

Tags: javascript

I have a problem. 
`docRef.get().then(...)` is a function which works asynchronously. Since it returns immediately, username will not be set. How could I get the value and set it to the variable `username`?

```
var username;
var kontostand;
var ticket;



firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function (user) {
  if (user) {
    // User is signed in.
    document.getElementById("user_div").style.display = "block";
    document.getElementById("login_div").style.display = "none";

    var docRef = db.collection("users").doc(user.uid);

    // Get the data from the user
    docRef.get().then(function (doc) {
      if (doc.exists) {
        //console.log("Document data:", doc.data());
        kontostand = doc.data().kontostand;
        ticket = doc.data().ticket;
        username = doc.data().username;
      } else {
        // doc.data() will be undefined in this case
        console.log("No such document!");
      }
    }).catch(function (error) {
      console.log("Error getting document:", error);
    });

    var user = firebase.auth().currentUser;

    if (user != null) {

      document.getElementById("user_para").innerHTML = "Welcome User : " + username;

    }
```

Comment: You can't assign variables asynchronously like that.

Comment: @evolutionxbox thanks for the comment. No it didn't.

Comment: Everything you want to happen after the `docRef.get()` needs to be inside the `function (doc)` callback. Or you use `async`/`await`.

Comment: @ChrisG thank you for your comment! And how the `function (doc)` looks like?

Comment: It should do, as that's what you're trying to do.

Comment: @evolutionxbox I didn't understood it. I'm a beginner...

Comment: Maybe consider explaining what you don't understand, or even what you're hoping to achieve? (Rather than saying "no it didn't")

Comment: @evolutionxbox thanks! I' don't get how to implemante the callback function

Comment: You already have the callback function. The first line inside is `if (doc.exists)`. A bit further down you're setting `username`, then the function basically ends. This is where you need to insert the rest of the code, the code that needs `username`.

Comment: @ChrisG thank you! I'm confused. i'm sorry.. :(